# Navigating between xaml pages using Hyperlink NavigateUri in windows 8 application

Tags: windows, xaml, hyperlink, microsoft-metro

In Windows phone 8 application, it is possible to navigate between XAML pages using the hyperlink as shown below

```
Hyperlink MyLink = new Hyperlink();
MyLink.NavigateUri = new Uri("/Views/SamplePage.xaml?entryId=" + entryId, UriKind.Relative);
```

I am creating dynamic hyperlinks inside IValueConverter based on the content. I am porting the application to Windows 8 and i could not use the same code, as windows 8 supports only the navigation using the Frame

this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SamplePage));

Is there any other way, i can use Hyperlinks to navigate between xaml pages in Windows 8 metro applications.

Or is there any way to get the current Frame from within IValueConverter to navigate between the pages?

Comment: Have you considered using [your own URI scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh779670.aspx)? - you can reinterpret that in your tap handler and do it with the `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SamplePage), itemId)` overload (where you've picked the itemId put of the URI.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are navigating in the ValueConverter- I personally would not do that.

Use the Frame object, create your own abstraction as a service, or use behaviors (which you of course can use converters with)

```
        <Grid x:Name="grid5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Background="Purple">
          <TextBlock x:Name="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="45" Text="Navigation with param" Margin="0,165,3,165"/>
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
              <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                 <core:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="Behaviors_And_Triggers.NewPage" Parameter="{Binding ElementName=TextBox,Path=Text}"/>
              </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
          </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Grid>
```

Dont forget to add the Behaviors SDK extension (Add Reference => Extensions => Behaviors) and namespace:

```
    xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

Note: Behaviors_And_Triggers.**NewPage** => NewPage is the name of the page!

Comment: Thanks Iris! Actually ValueConverter creates RichTextBlock with hyperlinks in the paragraph content and returns it to ContentPanel in the Frame. I cannot place Frame.Navigate inside the ValueConverter as Frame is not accessible from the ValueConverter.

Comment: IMHO I wouldn't let the valueconverter have that much responsibility. it is hard to test, handle expections and there is a performance penalty as well (even if ever so tiny). But anyway, post the converter code from WP and we can figur out the best way to solve this.